# How can I recognise possibly overlapping line segments in 2D?

Tags: pattern-recognition, matlab

I am given a 2-dimensional picture (black & white, white background) and it is assumed that there are some 'sticks' (basically 'thick lines' with different widths and lengths) that are (mostly) overlapping with one another.
I want to somehow recognize these sticks (where they are and how big they are).

Is there any approach you would recommend or, even better, anything that already exists? I am working with MatLab, but a general (theoretical) approach would be also fine! I am open to machine-learning, but I'd prefer classical algorithms here.

Comment: Have you looked at  Hough transforms? https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html

Comment: I did not! Thanks I'll check it out!